# How can I prevent Imageresizer using the Cloudfront plugin creating invalid urls?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, imageresizer

I host my images on Amazon S3 and only store one image size.

Up until now I have successfully been using [Imageresizer](http://imageresizing.net) to resize my images per request.

Now I need to introduce the Cloudfront CDN, which is giving me difficulties.

I have setup my config per the [documentation](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/cloudfront).

Like this:

```xml
<resizer>
    <diskcache dir="~/app_data" autoClean="true"/>
    <clientcache minutes="1440"/>
    <cloudfront redirectThrough="http://cdn.example.com" redirectPermanent="false"/>
    <plugins>
      <add name="DiskCache"/>
      <add name="ClientCache"/>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim"/>
      <add name="CloudFront"/> 
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

I then capture any URLs to my application like this:

```cs
private static void ImageResizer_OnPostAuthorizeRequestStart(
    IHttpModule sender2, HttpContext context)
{
    string path = Config.Current.Pipeline.PreRewritePath;
    if (!path.StartsWith(PathUtils.ResolveAppRelative("~/cdn/"),
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return;
    }

    Config.Current.Pipeline.SkipFileTypeCheck = true;
    Config.Current.Pipeline.ModifiedQueryString["cache"]
        = ServerCacheMode.Always.ToString();
}
```

So that Imageresizer can process them.

When it does it will change my URL to use the correct CDN path, but it also change the querystring params to semicolons:

> http://example.com/cdn/image.jpg?mode=crop&width=200

To this:

> http://mycdn.example.com/image.jpg;mode=crop;width=200

Unfortunately Amazon S3 doesn't like this and kicks it out as an Access Denied. However Amazon will happily server the original querystring.

So, how do I either preserve the querystring to prevent Imageresizer change the parameters to semicolons?

Or configure amazon, so that it will serve the image regardless of the semicolons?

Comment: You don't use CloudFront *instead* of S3, you use them both. Your cloudfront distribution should point to the server running ImageResizer, which in turn points to Amazon S3 with S3Reader. http://imageresizing.net/docs/cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use CloudFront *instead* of S3, **you use them both**. Your cloudfront distribution should point to the **server running ImageResizer**, which in turn accesses Amazon S3 with S3Reader. CloudFront should **never** point directly to S3; that would eliminate ImageResizer from the picture.

See http://imageresizing.net/docs/cloud

Comment: Hi, I have realised exactly that, that the whole purpose of the cloudfront plugin is to change the urls into the format I don't want so I have removed that. Thanks. Ps. Do you know where I can find some info how to point cloudfront to my app? Cheers.

Comment: The CloudFront docs are helpful. Remember you're creating  a download distribution to a custom origin server, not an S3 bucket.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingDownloadDistributions.html